# Printing values in a vertical column format in Python

Tags: python, list

Is there a way to print the values of list `A` in a vertical column format? I present the current and expected outputs.

```
A=[0.021090000000000005, 0.019535125946503053, 0.019398647830541613]
print(A)
```

The current output is

```
[0.021090000000000005, 0.019535125946503053, 0.019398647830541613]
```

The expected output is

```
[0.021090000000000005, 
0.019535125946503053, 
0.019398647830541613]
```

Comment: [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint)?

Comment: If the convenience printing functions don't serve your purpose, then you just need to do the printing yourself.  `for f in A:` / `print(f)`.

Comment: I need it so that I can export it to a column format in a graphing software.

Comment: What format exactly does that software expect‽ Is there a name for that format?

Comment: `print(*A, sep='\n')`?

Comment: I just want it in a column format, not row format which ```print``` is giving me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for c in a:
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the print function to format your output as you want.

```
print(*A, sep='\n')
```

This will add a newline after each element.